# How do I open an mp3 file and check for frames to validate it?

Tags: php, validation, mp3, mime-types

I can't seem to find something proper to really check if file is mp3.

Some files return as audio/mpeg and others as application/octet-stream while they are playable by media players.

Someone suggested opening the file and check for valid frames. I was wondering how am I going to start this with PHP. Someone give me some light.

I tried this, but the results are really not right.

```
$file = 'file_dir';
$finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
$mime = finfo_file($finfo, $file);
echo $mime;
```

Comment: You could try to read the id3 tags.

Comment: Check out [getID3()](http://getid3.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: im hosting with Godaddy, seems like they don't have the extention. "Call to undefined function id3_set_tag()"